It is possible that a Bluetooth keyboard that works under Android and Windows, will not work under Ubuntu?
So I got this generic Bluetooth keyboard without realizing that Linux was not specifically mentioned as a compatible OS: https://www.amazon.es/dp/B0CQXD8MFS
It works fine on Windows 10 and with my Pixel 8 Pro but under Ubuntu it is not even discovered in the settings. So I did some reading on this very forum and others to dive deeper and found that some Bluetooth keyboard seem to be more difficult to connect in Ubuntu, but in most cases there seems to be some type of workaround.
Not in this case, it seems. Ubuntu cannot even see the keyboard when using bluetoothctl in the shell. I actually wrote to the support of the keyboard maker and they confirmed it does not work under Linux.
Anyone knows how this could be possible? Isn't Bluetooth just Bluetooth, no matter the platform? (Please pardon my ignorance :))
Apologies: I did not mention my Ubuntu version. It is 22.04.4 LTS

[edit] your question to include which distro/version of Linux you are using - don't add to the comment trail.

It is not impossible :~).

@graham sorry, done!

does this answer help?
